# Why isn't my custom object being displayed when I call on it with a case statement?

Tags: c++, object, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, ostream

I just want to know why this custom Account object is not being shown on my console when I call the case (switch statement in main) on it? I won't bore anyone with the bulk of the code but this is the overloaded method in my .cpp file for the Account class:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const Account& acc) {
out << acc.name << '\n';
out << acc.accountBalance;
return out;
}
```

I'm a little confused as to whether the Account parameter should be a constant since I will be changing its state based on user input. I have taken out the const keyword but with no luck. The output is something like this 00AA87081.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Okay sorry guys, this is the switch statement in main:

```
switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        std::cout << "***User registration***" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Please enter your name." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> name;
        a->setName(name);
        break;

    case 2:
        std::cout << "How much credit do you want to deposit?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> input;
        a->deposit(input);
        std::cout << "Your account balance is now " << a->getAccountBalance() << std::endl;
        break;

    case 3:
        std::cout << "How many black and white pages do you want to print? - 1 credit per page" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> bPages;
        a->printBW(bPages);
        break;

    case 4:
        std::cout << "How many colour pages do you want to print? - 2.5 credits per page" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> cPages;
        a->printC(cPages);
        break;

    case 5:
        std::cout << "Please enter your promotional code." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> code;
        a->promo(code);
        break;

    case 6:
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
        break;

    case 7:
        std::cout << "Thank you" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
        break;

    default:
        std::cout << "Please enter a valid option." << std::endl;
    }

} while (choice !=7);
```

I have created the object above this and it does the same thing even if I call std::cout << a outside of the switch statement.

Comment: It sounds like you're probably doing something like `Account* a; /* other stuff */ std::out << a;`, but because you`won't bore anyone with the bulk of the code` it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: What makes you think that `switch`/`case` would cause the `operator<<` function to be called? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, or at least what you do with the `switch` statement.

Comment: "The output is'" or "the output should be"? Also, please show us the relevant parts of the main function.

Comment: `std::cout << *a << std::endl;` is what you wanted, closing as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like me and many others guessed, you are printing a *pointer*, which means that the output will be the contents of the pointer (i.e. the address it points to).

To print the *object* you need to dereference the pointer with the unary `*` operator:

```
std::cout << *a << '\n';
//           ^
//           |
// Notice asterisk here
```

Optionally, you can change the `operator<<` function to take a *pointer* to the class instead of a reference (or add a new overload of the function).